# Android image scale animation relative to center point

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, scale

I have an ImageView and I do a simple scale animation to it. Very standard code.

My scale_up.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1"
           android:fromYScale="1"
           android:toXScale="1.2"
           android:toYScale="1.2"
           android:duration="175"/>
</set>
```

My animation code:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_up);
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_image)).startAnimation(a);
```

The problem:

When the image scales it doesn't scale from the center, but from the top left corner. In other words, the scaled version of the image doesn't have the same point as the center, but it has the same top-left point.
Here's an image that explains what I mean:

[image: How the animation scales]
[image: How I want it]

The first image is how the animation scales and the second image is how I want it to scale. It should keep the center point the same.
I have tried setting up gravity on the image, on the container, aligning left or right, it always scales the same.

I'm using RelativeLayout for the main screen and ImageView is located into another RelativeLayout, but I tried other layouts, no change.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Forget the additional translation, set `android:pivotX`, `android:pivotY` to half the width and height and it will scale from the center of the image.

Comment: `pivotX` and `pivotY` should be set to half the `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` to be exact.

Answer (score 175):

`50%` is center of animated view.

`50%p` is center of parent

```
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.2"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="175"/>
```

Comment: for me 50% did the job (without p)

Comment: it should be without p if it's relative to the component width or height to which u r applying animation. p refers to the parent of the component to which ur applying the animation.

Comment: How to use `50%p` in Java files, instead of XML?

Comment: new ScaleAnimation(1.0f,1.2f,1.0f,1.2f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.5f);

Comment: There is also "a" - Animation.ABSOLUTE to set in px.

Answer (score 128):

The answer provided by @stevanveltema and @JiangQi are perfect but if you want scaling using code, then you can use my answer.

```
// first 0f, 1f mean scaling from X-axis to X-axis, meaning scaling from 0-100%
// first 0f, 1f mean scaling from Y-axis to Y-axis, meaning scaling from 0-100%
// The two 0.5f mean animation will start from 50% of X-axis & 50% of Y-axis, i.e. from center

ScaleAnimation fade_in =  new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
fade_in.setDuration(1000);     // animation duration in milliseconds
fade_in.setFillAfter(true);    // If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.
view.startAnimation(fade_in);
```

Comment: @T.Todua What errors? Please ask a new question and link back to this answer.

Comment: what if I want infinite repeats for the animation like
```
 android:repeatCount="infinite"
 android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the translate animation in your set to offset that. You'll probably need to tweak the toXDelta and toYDelta values to get it right so it keeps the image centered.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2"
        android:duration="175"/>
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-20%"
        android:toYDelta="-20%"
        android:duration="175"/>
</set>
```