# android can not use ViewPropertyAnimator's scale and translation in the same time

Tags: android, android-animation, viewpropertyanimator

I want to move one view over the other to make their left top corner aligned, and this is the views at the beginning of the animation:
[image: the views at the beginning of the animation]

and I use this code to do the animation:

```java
View view = findViewById(R.id.test_image);
View finalView = findViewById(R.id.final_wrapper);
float scale = new Random().nextFloat();            //this scale is only known at runtime 
view.animate().scaleX(scale).scaleY(scale)
      .translationX(finalWrapper.getLeft() - view.getLeft())
      .translationY(finalWrapper.getTop() - view.getTop())
      .setDuration(500).start();
```

this code works well if I only use scale or only use translation, but when I use them together, I can not move the red view right to the purple view's left top corner, there will always be some deviation：

[image: deviation over the two views]

So, how to move the red view over the purple view to make their left top corner aligned when using scale and translation in the meantime?

When I only use translation:

```java
view.animate()
      .translationX(finalWrapper.getLeft() - view.getLeft())
      .translationY(finalWrapper.getTop() - view.getTop())
      .setDuration(500).start();
```

It works fine:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out pivot setting before starting animation

```
view.setPivotX(0)
view.setPivotY(0)
```

by default pivot is set to center of view (50% of width and height), so scale animation is shrinking it "to center", thats why you got additional move distance

more info how to (pre-)set "animation center" point in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409506/android-image-scale-animation-relative-to-center-point)